# text index mongodb not working with accents

Tags: mongodb

This is my sample data:

```
>db.tests.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5aabbdecb71313f21cef8d85"), "id" : 1235, "word" : "comida" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5aabbdecb71313f21cef8d86"), "id" : 1234, "word" : "alimentación" }
```

I have a search index on word field. So I I can search not only by exact word:

```
    > db.tests.find({ $text: { $search: 'alimentación', $language: 'es', $diacriticSensitive: false } })
    { "_id" : ObjectId("5aabbdecb71313f21cef8d86"), "id" : 1234, "word" : "alimentación" }
    > db.tests.find({ $text: { $search: 'alimentos', $language: 'es', $diacriticSensitive: false } })

{ "_id" : ObjectId("5aabbdecb71313f21cef8d86"), "id" : 1234, "word" : "alimentación" }
```

However if my search text does not have accent, it's not matched:

```
> db.tests.find({ $text: { $search: 'alimentacion', $language: 'es', $diacriticSensitive: false } })
```

Getting the query plan information I got the difference between searching "alimentación" and "alimentacion":

In the first casa, parsedTextQuery get the stemming of the word:

```
    "winningPlan" : {
        "stage" : "TEXT",
        "indexPrefix" : {},
        "indexName" : "word_text",
        "parsedTextQuery" : {
            "terms" : [ 
                "aliment"
            ],
            "negatedTerms" : [],
            "phrases" : [],
            "negatedPhrases" : []
        },
```

In the second case not, as "alimentacion" does not exists:

```
"winningPlan" : {
    "stage" : "TEXT",
    "indexPrefix" : {},
    "indexName" : "word_text",
    "parsedTextQuery" : {
        "terms" : [ 
            "alimentacion"
        ],
        "negatedTerms" : [],
        "phrases" : [],
        "negatedPhrases" : []
    },
```

Any workaround using Mongo?

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/collation/

Comment: From https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/ text indexes only support simple binary comparison and do not support collation.

Comment: However it says that: With version 3, text index is diacritic insensitive, but it doesn't seem to be?

Comment: Ah, fair enough. I believe it falls into https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-29918?focusedCommentId=1722083&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-1722083 : *For now, truly diacritic-insensitive queries should use either collation or a text index language of "none" (but will lose out on the benefit of stemming).* so no dice I'm afraid.